# Numpy array shape after extraction from Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I have a column in a Dataframe where each cell has a `(300,)` shaped numpy array.

When I extract the values of this column using the `.values` method, I get a numpy array of shape `(N,)` where `N` is the number of rows of the Dataframe. And each element of `N` is a `(300,)` array. I would have expected the extracted shape to be `(Nx300)`.

So I would like to shape of the extracted column to be `(Nx300)`. I tried using `pd.as_matrix()` but this still gets me a numpy array of shape `(N,)`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html), connvert to list and cast to `array`:

```
a = np.random.randint(10, size=300)
print (a.shape)
(300,)

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'A':[a,a,a]})

arr = np.array(np.concatenate(df.values).tolist())
print (arr.shape)
(3, 300)
```